# Change x ticks values/format/frequency on Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to learn Seaborn and was messing around with formatting and was wondering if there was a way for me to change the formatting on the X axis?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Plays")
plt.title("Daily Plays from 2017 - 2018")
sns.lineplot(data=spotify_data['Despacito'], label="Despacito");
sns.lineplot(data=spotify_data['HUMBLE.'], label="HUMBLE.");
```

[Unformatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l07v.png)

But I would like one that has each month per tick. How will I do it with just Seaborn, matplotlib and numpy?